# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, datagrip

I have following PL/SQL Trigger I want to execute to my Oracle XE Server. For a school project we need to do autoincrementation with triggers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_br_i_firma_id_autoinc
    BEFORE INSERT ON FIRMA
    FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(new.FIRMA_ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT seq_firma.NEXTVAL into :new.FIRMA_ID
    FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

It seems to work because it completes with just a warning but when I now run inserts, it says that the Trigger do not work.
But when I run the Trigger via SQLWorkbench it works just fine without any warning and I can then run Insert commands via DataGrip again.

DataGrip consoles gives me this after execution:

```
AUTOMATENMANAGER> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_br_i_firma_id_autoinc
                    BEFORE INSERT ON FIRMA
                    FOR EACH ROW
                  WHEN(new.FIRMA_ID IS NULL)
                  BEGIN
                    SELECT seq_firma.NEXTVAL into :new.FIRMA_ID
                    FROM DUAL;
                  END;
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] [99999][17110] Warning: execution completed with warning
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] completed in 20 ms
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] 1:6:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] raise return select update while with <an identifier>
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] The symbol "" was ignored.
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] 2:45:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] .
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] ( , % from indicator
```

I searched all questions regarding this error message but I can't seem to find one that fits...
Do I have an syntax error or did I miss something?

Comment: Works fine in 18c when I add another line with '/' on it. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9f144c7f68a21993671a29f4bf9f7b62)

Comment: As an additional observation, it isn't necessary to use `select ... into` in your trigger. You can simply say `new.FIRMA_ID := seq_firma.NEXTVAL;` That will require less processing overhead and scale more efficiently.

Comment: When the trigger is in an invalid state after attempting to compile with Datagrip, is there anything in `user_errors`?

Comment: What would I be looking for in user_errors? @WilliamRobertson 
In there are only triggers with the warning message but also with the attribute ERROR

Comment: You want to check user_errors where name = 'TR_BR_I_FIRMA_ID_AUTOINC' and attribute = 'ERROR'. That will give you the line, position and text of each error. Normally professional development tools for PL/SQL show you this information and highlight the line automatically. Perhaps DataGrip has some setting for this, but I've never used it.

Comment: Just to add, the line numbers reported in user_errors start at the first `begin` or `declare` keyword, so line 2 would be the one containing `SELECT`. Tools such as PL/SQL Developer and SQL Developer adjust the displayed error line number to count from the top. I don't know whether DataGrip does this or not, though.

Answer (score 0):

Code you posted works just fine on Oracle 11g. I don't have 10g any more, but - I'd say that it should work on that version as well. Here's a demo:

```
SQL> create table firma (firma_id number, name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq_firma;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_br_i_firma_id_autoinc
  2      BEFORE INSERT ON FIRMA
  3      FOR EACH ROW
  4  WHEN(new.FIRMA_ID IS NULL)
  5  BEGIN
  6      SELECT seq_firma.NEXTVAL into :new.FIRMA_ID
  7      FROM DUAL;
  8  END;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into firma (name) values ('Audi');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from firma;

  FIRMA_ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 Audi

SQL>
```

---

This looks suspicious:

```
[2021-07-08 20:18:04] 1:6:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting
                      ---
                      I read this as "line 1, column 6"
```

If that's so, position of line 1 / column 6 is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr
------
123456
```

Maybe that "DataGrip consoles" (I have no idea what it is) doesn't support `or replace` clause, so - perhaps you should try combination of `DROP + CREATE`, i.e.

```
drop trigger tr_br_i_firma_id_autoinc;
create trigger tr_br_i_firma_id_autoinc
  before insert on firma
  ...
end;
/
```

Comment: I tried it with your answer and tried to drop and then create it. Sadly the same error message came on, also in the same column 1:6:PLS-00103

Comment: Hm, sorry to hear that. As I said, code itself is perfectly OK and I suspect it is about the DataGrip, but - as I don't use it, I can't tell *what* would that be.